# How to import multiple CSS pages into one main CSS page, and then import the main CSS page to the HTML page?

Tags: html, css, import

I have a folder, with one .html page. Inside that folder I have a folder called "stylesheets"

Inside the "stylesheets folder, I multiple CSS pages, a "main.css" page, and four others called, "links.css, images.css, headers.css and text.css.

I'm trying to import these four CSS pages, to the main CSS page, and then import the main CSS page to the HTMl. All the CSS pages work correctly because I've tested them alone. This is what I have:

---------------------------------------... 
In the main.css page I have: 
---------------------------------------... 
    @charset "utf-8"; 
    /* CSS Document */

```
@import url('/stylesheets/links.css'); 
@import url('/stylesheets/text.css'); 
@import url('/stylesheets/images.css'); 
@import url('/stylesheets/headers.css');
```

---------------------------------------... 
Then in the HTML page I have: 
---------------------------------------... 
     
     
     
    Insert Title

```
<style> 
@import url('/stylesheets/main.css'); 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

---------------------------------------...

It does not work, please help because this is required in an assignment for school. I have searched, but cannot find how to do it.

Comment: Is that all the code you have in HTML? It is missing opening tags.

Comment: I'd recommend using SASS, http://sass-lang.com/guide - check the import section of the guide, SASS is a CSS Preprocessor and compiles into a css file. Using CSS @import has speed issues because of the way browsers render html information, they need the CSS information as immediately upon load as possible and making url requests forces the browser to wait on server requests before rendering, see http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 0):

Within main.css, the file paths need to relative to the CSS file itself, not your HTML document. So assuming all your css is in fact inside the one folder, change the filepaths to simply `@import url('links.css');` and so on. Keep the import in the html as is.